# Change a variable based on a target in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, target

How can I change the value of a variable based on one of the targets in Makefile? Something link this:

```
target:
    DEFINES += -DDEPLOY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your make is GNU make,
[target-specific variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)
might meet the purpose.
This facility allows almost the same notation as in the question
like the following:

```
target: DEFINES += -DDEPLOY
```

Comment: I get this error: make: *** No rule to make target `target'.  Stop.

Comment: @Meysam: Hi. Does target-specific variable meet your objective?
If so, other rules and recipes need to be prepared as usual.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),target)
 DEFINES += DDEPLOY
 endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like:

```
target:
    DEFINES="${DEFINES} -DDEPLOY"
```

and on the compiler invocation line:

```
gcc -c blablabla ... ${DEFINES}
```

Not sure if it work, don't know if it is compatible with every shell...